# IF condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    $code=document.write(geoip_country_code());
```

The `$code` produces the value as IN for ip address in india.. I want to hide some values when the `$code` is US. So i write the code as follws..

```
if($code=='US')
    {
    </script>
    <table width="200" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    }
    else
    {
    </script>

      <table width="200" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>



     <script type="text/javascript">
        }
        </script>
```

i used if condition inside javascript, but not working...Is it possible to use if condition in javascript like above??

**Thanks**

Comment: JavaScript isn't like PHP...

Comment: Javascript variables are not preceded by `$`, remove that $, and make it 
`var code=document.write(geoip_country_code());`

Comment: @xFortyFourx They can be if one prefers. JS variables can be called almost whatever you like

Comment: You can do similar thing in PHP, not in javascript. You can put conditions in javascript and fill the contents of an element, but it's a different approach than what you're trying to do.

Comment: each <script></script> must contain a complete script. You can't use javascript that way.

Comment: @Bojangles silly me :)

Comment: Its valid to use if in javascript, but you cannot directly write HTML tags inside a javascript, you should `document.write('<h1>Hello World</h1>')`. This is how you should do it

Comment: first of all you can not define $code as variable in javascript. in javascript you need to use var instead of $.

Comment: @xFortyFourx No worries `:)`. For example, some developers denote variables storing jQuery objects with a preceding `$`

Comment: @Bojangles yep, it struck me the second after you said that. Also, I noticed his code only later on, he's expecting javascript to work like php :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($code=='US')
{

var t = "<table width=\"200\" border=\"0\"><tr>"+
    "<td>1</td>"+
    "<td>2</td>"+
  "</tr>"+
  "<tr>"+
    "<td>3</td>"+
    "<td>4</td>"+
  "</tr>"+
"</table>";

document.write(t);

}
else
{


var t = "<table width=\"200\" border=\"0\"><tr>"+
    "<td>A</td>"+
    "<td>B</td>"+
  "</tr>"+
  "<tr>"+
    "<td>C</td>"+
    "<td>D</td>"+
  "</tr>"+
"</table>";

document.write(t);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

js:

```
$code=document.write(geoip_country_code());

if($code=='US') {
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display = 'block';
}
```

html:

```
<table width="200" border="0" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="200" border="0" id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#table1,
#table2 { display: none; }
```

Comment: @DevangRathod - Yes, definitely. You can even declare a variable that is just `$` on its own, or even `_` on its own. (Try it and see for yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to end the script-tags and start them again in the body if the if.

Instead you should toggle the visibility on the tables using css and preferably JQuery.

Something like

```
if($code == 'US')
  $("#mytable").show();
else
  $("#myothertable").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing JS with PHP. JS cannot hide code, since the code you are operating on is already passed into the browser as source code and parsed. If you want to hide the code, do it in PHP before it gets on the browser.

The best you can do is hide it from display (not from code) in JS using `display:none` on the elements you want to hide.